# Extract all numbers in a string that do not end with a decimal or a parenthesis in R

Tags: r, regex, string

Sorry for updating my request in light of some answers. I want to get the frequency of numbers in a string. Sometimes, the numbers are list items like those ending with a period or a parenthesis; I don't want to count such numbers. I am interested in whole numbers, numbers with % symbols, numbers in text, and decimals.
I am unable to get the correct count of matches. I am adding a decimal number to the list too.

My code is

```r
test <- c("25 1) 10) 15) 20] 10%", "1. 1.", "110 20 30", "1. 10.5", "one two")
str_count(test, "\\d+(?![\\.\\b])(?![\\)])|one|two")
```

The output is

```r
[1] 5 0 3 2 2
```

What am I missing here? The correct output should be

```r
[1] 2 0 3 1 2
```

Comment: Your question asks to "extract" and yet you're using `str_count` (emphasis on ***count***), what am I missing? Try `str_extract_all`

Comment: My bad. I want the count. Not the extract. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make use of the character class `[.)]` to match either a dot or closing parenthesis:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)*\b(?![.)\]])%?|\b(?:one|two)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*\b` Match 1+ digits and optionally repeat `.` and 1+ digits followed by a word boundary
- `(?![.)\]])` Negative lookahead, assert not `.` `)` `]` directly to  the right of the current position
- `%?` Match an optional `%`
- `|` Or
- `\b(?:one|two)\b` Match whole words between word boundaries

The word boundaries `\b` are to prevent a partial word match:

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQqt0s/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##NYzLCsIwEEX3@YoxUMj4CEklmyLkQ5wgthYpSAJpRIT@e5wWXFw4nAsn1/qa@nzPXzWXPMVnRiHKOBe4nGBQsnVgEazhOYTWBOZGHkFaDVZvYA17OJu/NdqtmOII5ZMkCg7fhvSORa1hvoh6osdB@Y5Ir4R7VsrvrhqJQsDGL5voOLJwhG0vsdYf)

Example

```
library(stringr)

test <- c("25 1) 10) 15) 20] 10%", "1. 1.", "110 20 30", "1. 10.5", "one two")
str_count(test, "\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*\\b(?![.)\\]])%?|\\b(?:one|two)\\b")
```

Output

```
[1] 2 0 3 1 2
```

Comment: @r2evans Sharp! All those backslashes... Let me update that all the way

Comment: yes, R lives in backslash-purgatory ... it's taking some of the most-frustrating from both C and Lisp in both parentheses and backslashes. FYI, it can be simplified _visually_ using R's new-ish raw-strings: `str_count(test, r"|\b\d+(?:\.\d)*\b(?![.)])|")` (where I use `"|...|"` instead of `"{...}"` or `"[...]"` or `"(...)"` to avoid most visual confusion with regexes. `|` is not perfect but slightly better imho. I have never understood the _need_ to add the extra characters to the opening/closing quotes, the leading `r` is rather unambiguous.)

Comment: @r2evans Should be ok now. I am clearly not an R user, just a regex fan, thanks for the pointers!

Comment: no worries, there are some regex gurus who add answers to [tag:r]/[tag:regex] but not taking R's backslash-heck into account, can be frustrating for new users, I really appreciate the extra effort!

Comment: Excellent! Your timely help is most appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I am running into a problem if the list contains 10] as an item. I tried using [.)]]. It is not helping. Can you suggest a way out The forth bird?

Comment: There is another issue. I also want to count number formats having % symbol like 5% etc. I tried this solution and it is not working.

Comment: @SamarthA That is because at the moment of answering you question, that issue was not yet in scope. But in that case you could write the pattern as `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)*\b(?![.)\]])%?|\b(?:one|two)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/xQqt0s/1

Comment: I checked and it worked! Thanks for updating the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)

test <- c("25 1) 10) 15) 20] 10%", "1. 1.", "110 20 30", "1. 10.5", "one two")
result <- str_count(test, "\\b\\d+(\\.\\d+)?(?![\\.\\)\\]])%?\\b|one|two")

print(result)
```

Comment: This looks fine at first glance. But if my list contains a decimal number, the output does not include that count. I want to count decimal numbers too (10.5 should be counted but 10. should not be counted).

Comment: @SamarthA The `regex` is updated. Check it out.

Comment: can you please help with my updated question? I am also interested in % format of numbers.

Comment: @SamarthA The answer is updated again.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to simplify the regex by eliminating the space through `strsplit`

edit: updated with new string

edit2: updated with new string

```
library(stringr)

sapply(strsplit(test, " "), function(x) 
  sum(str_count(x, "^\\d+%*$|^\\d+\\.\\d+%*$|one|two")))
[1] 2 0 3 1 2
```

Comment: What is the "\" before (x)? Sorry, I did not understand.

Comment: @SamarthA It's short for "function(x)", introduced around R v4.1.0

Comment: Oh mine. I have not updated my R.